# I am having problems with sp_depends, it says that my database is invalid for the operation

Tags: database, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

So i have this database called crm and i need to select a list of all the stored procedures that depend on a specific table/column.
I did some research and i learned about sp_depends, i tried to execute but it reports me and error.
Here's the code:

`EXEC sp_depends @objname = 'TCdPost'`

TCdPost stands for a column that contains the postal code.
As i execute the query i get an error that says:

`The object 'TCdPost' does not exist in database 'crm' or is invalid for this operation.`

Does anyone know what causes this error or some better ways to select all the stored procedures that depend on a table/column?

Im using SQL Server 2008 R2

Thank you.

Comment: As [MSDN](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933275%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) says, the types of objects you can pass to see dependences for `can be a table, view, stored procedure, or trigger` - you are passing a column name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This feature will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server. Avoid using this feature in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use this feature. Use sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities and sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities instead.

So would suggest not to use it.

Also, you are passing wrong object name to the procedure.

Try This one:

```
USE crm
Go
EXEC sp_depends 'dbo.YourTableName'
```

If you want the more specific details for columns,  [refer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933275(v=sql.80).aspx) this.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
USE crm 
EXEC sp_depends 'TCdPost'
```

or if you to want to view the dependencies of the table you can see it by right click the table and then click "View Dependencies" thanks